# Creating a point moving along a circle in MATLAB with speed and radius defined by the user

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, curve, scilab

I am looking to create a simple circle graph within MATLAB in which the model shows the point moving along the circle with radius and angular velocity defined by the user.

Angular velocity in RADIANS/SEC

I am relatively new at MATLAB coding so any help would be very useful!

I tried this code:

```
r=1;
t = 0:.01:2*pi;
x = r*cos(t);
y = r*sin(t);
comet(x,y);
```

But when I change the 0.01 value the point doesn't move faster, it just skips more of the curve, also i'm unsure if the  increments are in radians.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Moving faster = skipping more of the curve when you are simply adjusting the step size.

Comment: yes, that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

**Edited version**: See edit history for previous version.

```
Radius = 10;
AngularVelocity = 5; % in deg / s
AngleStep = 0.1
Angles = AngleStep : AngleStep : 2*pi;
CircleX = [Radius]; % empty array
CircleY = [0]; % empty array

%Initial zero-angle plot whose data we'll keep updating in the for loop:
a = plot([CircleX,CircleX], [CircleY,CircleY], 'r:');
hold on;
b = plot(CircleX, CircleY, 'o', 'markeredgecolor', 'k', 'markerfacecolor','g');
axis([-Radius, +Radius, -Radius, +Radius]); % make sure the axis is fixed
axis equal; % make x and y pixels of equal size so it "looks" a circle!
hold off;

for t = Angles
  CircleX(end+1) = Radius * cos (t); % append point at end of CircleX array
  CircleY(end+1) = Radius * sin (t); % append point at end of Circley array
  set(a,'xdata',CircleX,'ydata',CircleY); % update plot 'a' data
  set(b,'xdata', CircleX(end), 'ydata', CircleY(end)); % update plot 'b' data
  drawnow; % ensure intermediate frames are shown!
  pause(AngleStep/AngularVelocity) % pause the right amount of time!
end
```

This edit has made two changes compared to the previous version:

1. Instead of redrawing, now we're updating the data of an existing plot. This is generally faster as matlab doesn't have to redraw `axes` objects (i.e. the containers that hold the plot)
2. I increased AngleStep from 0.01 to 0.1. This means there's 10 times less angles to draw, so you can afford to draw then 10 times slower, therefore it becomes less likely that matlab will be unable to draw because of overhead. Having said that, this is at the cost of a less perfect circle. Try with AngleStep=1 to see what I mean.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help, just one thing, i cant seem to change the velocity, if i put 1 or 100 the difference is almost unoticiable

Comment: @RicardoSilvestre I didn't want to get *too* advanced because you said you were a beginner. Yes you're right, the reason for this is the time it takes to *redraw* the whole plot, matlab just isn't fast enough, so this "eats into" the time. If you put slower velocities you'll see it really does get slower. There *are* ways to make this faster, by updating the plot data directly instead of redrawing, but this is slightly more complex. Would you still like me to show you?